# how do i fit my imageicon into the JButton fully and the buttons to shift below?

Tags: java

I am trying to fit my image below into the JButton but the image is not fully fit into the jbutton and there is a gap between the image and the button borders.How do i make the image appear fully on my JButton jbtstart?In addition how do i shift the JPanel containing the JButtons to another location as it appears at the top?

```
private JButton jbtstart;
private JButton jbtabout = new JButton("About");
private JButton jbtcredits = new JButton("Credits");
private JButton jbtexit = new JButton("Exit");
private JButton jbtImg;




//private static int gridSize = 2;

public GUI_interface()
{
    super("GUIinterface");
}



public void createAndDisplayGUI()
{   

    jbtstart= new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\start button.png"));

    jbtstart.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel back=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\background.png"));



    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    //p.setLayout(null);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,80,15));




    back.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    p1.add(jbtstart);
    p1.add(jbtabout);
    p1.add(jbtcredits);
    p1.add(jbtexit);

    back.add(p1);

    jbtstart.addActionListener(this);
    jbtabout.addActionListener(this);
    jbtcredits.addActionListener(this);
    jbtexit.addActionListener(this);



    setContentPane(back);



    JFrame frame = new JFrame("f");
   frame.setTitle("Cooking App");
   frame.setSize(300,250);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.add(back);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Could you add images for current and desired effect so we can get a more concise idea of your goal?

Comment: Hi i am unable to add images to the page,but i can post this link via facebook to the picture.This is the current result:https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=352295531591473&set=a.352295364924823.1073741827.100004330877224&type=3&theater

Comment: This is the desired result(note that the image is altered and not the actual one):https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=352296371591389&set=a.352295364924823.1073741827.100004330877224&type=3&theater

Comment: Sorry im unable to alter the button images,but i want the"start" image to basically fit into the button without the white gap